# Add extra parameter to every WCF call

Tags: wcf, testing, wcf-security, claims

We have WCF services (web hosted in IIS) separatd by domains. We added some claim based security by adding ClaimsAuthorizationManager and overriding the CheckAccess method. Basicaly, we check if the ClaimsPrincipal have the permission needed to execute the method.

**Inside the service method :**

```
public DemandePaeDto ObtenirInfoDemandePAE(int idPreDemande, int numeroSequencePreDemande)
    {
        if (!ClaimsPrincipal.Current.CheckAccess(Management, "DoSomething"))
            return null;
```

**Inside the ClaimsAuthorizationManager :**

```
public class FacadeClaimsAuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Principal;
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;

        foreach (var action in context.Action)
        {
            switch (resource)
            {
                case "Management":
                case "Sales":
                case "Product":
                    if (user.HasClaim(OurOwnCustomClaimTypes.Permission, action.Value))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                //Pour les cas non gérés
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is when we need to test the services functionalities with WCF Storm of other test tool, we don't have the claims because we set the security mode to false. So we would like to add a custom parameter to all calls. That way we'd be able to bypass by returning true in the CheckAccess method. I've think about MessageInpectors, but still am wondering if it's the right approach. I wouldn't like to add the param to the contracts, because I'd have to modify every call in the application.

Do you have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a different `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` for your tests. Just derive a different version and use that in your testing environment. It could return true on all call for example.

Comment: That is the goal to return true in the ClaimsAuthorizationManager, but since we also test the UI in this environment, we need to keep it as is. We need to test only the services but without impacting the UI usage.

Comment: I don't see how any kind of UI impacts your ability to test against another authorization manager in your service. Can you explain?

Comment: I want the UI to keep using the actual ClaimsAuthorizationManager for security tests. But I don't want it when we tests only the services.